# How can I grab a streaming video manifest from a web page?

Tags: shell, download, video-streaming

Inspired by Christmas, I started writing a Linux shell script that essentially grabs today's episode of the [daily children's Christmas show](http://www.dr.dk/tv/se/boern/ramasjang/jullerup-faergeby/jullerup-faergeby-3-24#!/) from a TV station's online library. My script does the following:

1. check how many episodes are already downloaded to identify which is next,
2. open the TV station's web page for that next episode,
3. programmatically click in the embedded streaming object to activate the stream,
4. programmatically click "pause" so it doesn't actually play out loud,
5. **missing:** grab the video manifest from the browser,
6. use the [AdobeHDS](https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/blob/master/AdobeHDS.php) script to download the fragments and join them into one FLV file,
7. use `avconv` to convert the FLV file into a friendlier MP4 format.

Well, my **step "5" is broken**, and that's where I need your help! My problem is that the manifest file doesn't become available until after the streaming object has been activated, and I don't know how to access that programmatically. Here's my **manual workaround:**

1. once the web page loads and the script has clicked on "play", the manifest becomes available,
2. I use [Adblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/)'s *"open blockable items"* to search for "manifest" in the page's resources,
3. I *manually(!)* copy the manifest URL into a shell `read` prompt. From here, the script continues automatically.

Obviously, this manual step prevents me from setting the script up as a cron task.

Here's a [Pastebin snapshot of my script](http://pastebin.com/Pwn7nqgD).

*Disclaimer:*  I'm totally new to programming, and I realize that a shell script is not really "programming" but sort-kinda is. I am doing this as an interesting exercise and to learn some basic concepts. You can say it's not mission-critical ;-) but you know how you start doing something, only to realize you need to dig deeper into some detail, and then deeper still, and so on. This is where I am finding myself right now. I didn't expect things to become this complicated, but I guess most programmers have that experience at some point :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use
[HDS Link Detector](http://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/hds-link-detector)
to capture this information. Example output

```
http://drod01c-vh.akamaihd.net/z/all/clear/streaming/ca/547d12116187a20e4c6282ca/Jullerup-Faergeby--3-24-_ecfaae965b3344f2907ebf19d852761a_,1125,562,248,.mp4.csmil/manifest.f4m?g=REZLVPFXIRIX&hdcore=3.5.0&plugin=aasp-3.5.0.151.81
```